# How to find out what event is firing on what element

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firebug

Is there a tool (or something in firebug) that will tell me what events just fired and more importantly on what elements they were bound to?

I have a number of javascript "includes", some minified, some not.  I am experiencing some odd behaviour that I want to turn off, but I cannot find what is causing it.

I have a form showing in a "popup" and when I try to click on one of the input boxes, the "popup" closes, so some event bind somewhere is causing this.

The problem is, I don't know what element has this spurious event bound to it.  The problem also occurs if I click anywhere inside the popup (and on the background mask that is covering the rest of the page, but that's acceptable)

I am using firefox, so anything I can type in the console is also an option.  The eventys in the multiple javascript files are done in various ways, some through jquery, some using inline attributes (eg. onclick="..."), some using just javascript.

I certainly don't want to go and add some line of code to every possible event in every javascript file.

I have spent over an hour trying to hunt down this dom element and have already eliminated the obvious ones like the divs containing the popup and the body tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM modifications can be tracked down using the [*Break On Mutate* option](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Break_On_Mutate) within Firebug. It can be activated by clicking the related button ( [image: Break On Mutate button] ) within the [*HTML* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel). Note that the [*Script* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel) has to be enabled for this to work.

There are also several other [*Break On ...* features](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Break_On_...), which may help you finding the right position within the code for a specific event.

Furthermore Firebug 2.0 introduced an [*Events* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Events_Side_Panel), which displays all events bound to the element selected within the *HTML* panel. If libraries like jQuery are used, it will even allow you to investigate the user-defined function wrapped by the library function in case you enable the option *Show Wrapped Listeners* as described in [the answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24337113/432681).