# jquery mobile event.preventdefault() not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

Weird problem, and apparently not uncommon with jquery mobile. I have a two-item listview popup that is intended to allow users to switch views via `<a href="someurl.com">`. Each choice is intended to display json data on the same page. I don't want the `href` to take the viewer to another page, so I am trying to use `event.preventdefault()`.

But after much research I still cannot prevent an `href` from jumping to google.com, even though (I think) I am using `event.preventdefault();` properly.

here's the relevant html:

```
<div data-role='popup' id='popupSwitchView' data-theme='none'>
    <ul data-role='listview'>
        <legend>Choose a view</legend>
        <li><a href='javascript:;' data-role='button' data-transition='fade' data-mini='true' class='ui-btn-active switchview' id='ABC' name='theView' value='ABC'>ABC</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='http://google.com' data-role='button' data-transition='fade' data-mini='true' class='switchview' id='DEF' name='theView' value='DEF'>DEF</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

... and here's the jquery:

```
$('#DEF').on('click', function () {
    event.preventDefault();
```

I wondered if it's the way I'm using the selector, but I tested the selector with the same code [here](http://sk.kapsi.fi/interactive-jquery-tester.html) and it seems my selector is fine.

Chrome console isn't showing any error. Any thoughts on what I'm missing here?

**EDIT**

I neglected to mention that the above html and jquery are part of a php variable `$html_jq`, which is echoed from another php file.

i.e., `file1.php` echoes `$html_jq`, which is defined in `file2.php`.

Comment: you need to put --  event  -- inside the brackets so it gets picked up -- $('#DEF').on('click', function (event) { -- also try -- event.stopImmediatePropagation()  -- it Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

Comment: @Tasos thanks, yes, tried that -- also tried $('#DEF').on('click', function (e) { e.event.preventDefault();... neither worked. Nor did event.stopImmediatePropagation() unfortunately.

Comment: yeah they dont always work. What you can do is set up a flag eg onclick you set a variable to on state. Then set a timeout to a second or so to clear the on state to off. Now in your other click functions you check -- if state is on then dont run the code. This is kind of a work around and work very well

Comment: thanks again. my edit might shed some light on this (i.e. the html and jq are in a php variable that is being echoed) . I didn't think it was relevant yesterday but am starting to suspect it is

Comment: I always use like this:
`$('#DEF').on('click', function(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    event.preventDefault();
});`

Answer (score 0):

I have I think part (maybe 0.01 percent) of the answer. The selector isn't grabbing anything, which explains the uncooperative behaviour. I think it means jquery mobile and jquery itself are handling this event behind the scenes and they're referring to something else and obviously not my selector.

As was suggested in [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472334/how-to-find-what-code-is-run-by-a-button-element-in-chrome-using-developer-tools), I drilled into what actually happens when you click on that link, and it's pretty weird.

i.e., with "click" checked in Chrome Developer Tools `Source` tab -> `Event Listener Breakpoints` -> `Mouse` -> `Click` and then hitting `f11` until it stops jumping around, I discovered what appears to be an inescapable `While` loop in which the event gets hung up. That While loop appears to be in `jquery-2.1.1.js` on line 4541.

This is interesting under-the-hood stuff which will prove very valuable at some point, but I am unsure what to do here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As of this date, this problem happens when you try and use JQM 1.4.5 with anything after Jquery 2.1.4

See [Jquery mobile github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/8381)