# How to get a list of JavaScript files that are executed when event is fired?

Tags: javascript, file, events, knockout.js, google-chrome-devtools

In complicated system, how can I get a list of all the JavaScript files that has been fired during button click or click to input field?

Can I do it with chrome dev-tools or are there any other solutions? If I can do it with chrome dev-tools then how?

**Problem that I am facing**: I am trying to find file what contains method which I can intercept to add my custom validation before button click redirects to another page? File names are useful to me because the system is following clean code rules.

**UPDATE:**
I found [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472334/how-to-find-what-code-is-run-by-a-button-element-in-chrome-using-developer-tools), but none of provided solution seems to work (I am certain that breakpoints are not working). The `Visual Event` extension suggested by @Carles Alcove in referred post, lead me to `knockout.js` file. In that file I added `console.trace()` function (second image is the result) as suggested by @guest271314. First image is when I inspected the button with dev-tools as suggested by @user3297291

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include `console.trace()`, `console.profile()` and `console.profileEnd()` within `click` event handler, review line numbers of files at `console` and `Profiles` tab at `DevTools`

Comment: The `Profiles` tab helped me a lot (thanks for pointing that out). I could see some of the files that where fired - only issue is that it is not quite exact. It would be perfect if the profiler could be set to start recording when event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

You can check an overview of event listeners attached to an element in the developer tools by doing:

- Right mouse button on an element
- *Inspect element* in context menu
- Click *Event Listeners* tab in the right panel of the dev. tools
- Check for `mouseup` or `click` events.

[image]

You'll see the attached methods and their file names. I'm not sure if this works for every kind of event listener (e.g. if the event is bound to a parent element), but it's a quick way to predict what might be called.